# 19.10: I think I messed up installing BlueGriffon

Tags: bluegriffon

I installed [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) version 3.3 today in Ubuntu 19.10. It shows as installed in the addon section of applications.

Now how do I launch it?

I am so frustrated. I am not sure if I did it wrong or if I missed some command or something.

I am very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publisher of Blue Griffon does not make their application's user manual freely available; [it must be purchased](http://bluegriffon.org/#manual). Therefore, these instructions are provided on a 'best available' basis.

Open the Nautilus file manager by clicking on the file drawer icon. Look in /usr/share/applications and in ~/.local/share/applications for **bluegriffon.desktop**.  Once found, please right-click on it and check its Properties. It should be set as Executable; if it is not, make it so.

Alternatively, open a terminal window, change to the bluegriffon directory and launch the app with

```
cd ~/bluegriffon  
sudo ./bluegriffon
```

Comment: I just wanted to test this program to see how I like it. I installed the free version just to give it a test. I was able to find it in my applications file. I found the .desktop file and make a desktop shortcut. Everything is working great. Thank you for your help. I am able to use this now.